# How to add multiple small ROI (Region of interest) to form an image in numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a list of small ROI (Region of interest) of an image, represented by numpy array. How can I add or stitch the ROI together to form a larger image (numpy array)? Each ROI is 50x50 and I want it to stitch together into 500x400 image.
I know how to do it using basic loops, but is there a numpy function that I can use?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes. Using `np.vstack` or `np.hstack` depending on how you want them stitched. My advice is to stitch all the ROIs horizontally, and then stitch the resultant rows vertically.

Comment: @Shiva, it works! Thank you so much :)

Comment: Sure, happy to help. I'll go ahead and post it as an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.vstack` or `np.hstack` depending on how you want them stitched.

An example of `np.vstack`:

```
>>> a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
>>> b = np.array([2, 3, 4])
>>> np.vstack((a,b))
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 4]])
```

And, an example for `np.hstack`:

```
>>> a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
>>> b = np.array([2, 3, 4])
>>> np.hstack((a,b))
array([1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4])
```

My advice is to stitch all the ROIs horizontally, and then stitch the resultant rows vertically.

So, you first stitch 8 `50x50` ROIs horizontally using `np.hstack` to form a row. Do this 10 times to get 10 rows, each of dimension `50x400`.

Now, stitch all the resultant rows vertically using `np.vstack` to get your image of dimension `500x400`.

Let me know if I've gotten anything wrong.